# Why IFrame or Frame element is behaving differently in different platforms?

Tags: iframe, webdriver, frame, watir

I am automating my web-application using Ruby and Watir - Webdriver. In which a dialogue is designed inside a frame. So when I am trying to get the reference of the IFrame, I'm using below ruby, watir - webdriver code.

```
ref = driver.iframe(:id => 'settings_dlg')
```

the above line returning a reference when I am running my script on my laptop(Windows 7 + Chrome), but not returning in Virtual machine(Windows 7 + Chrome).

when I replace "iframe" with "frame" in the above line it could return reference in Virtual machine, But not returning not in my laptop
i.e.,

```
ref = driver.frame(:id => 'settings_dlg')
```

What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Does the problem only have with a very specific page or does it also happen if you create a simple page with just the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

#iframe will only match an html element with an iframe tag, and #frame will only match an html element with a frame tag. So, there is likely something else going on.

You can also try this, which forces it to be whatever it finds:

`driver.element(id: 'settings_dlg').to_subtype`

(I'm assuming driver is an instance of Watir::Browser)